# Show username value from Database to textview

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I am new in Java, I want to show the username value from my Table in SQLite Database after successful login into my TextView in layout activity_home.xml
I don't know how to get username value with my code here.

The code for my TextView in my activity_home.xml layout's

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/nameuser"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"/>
```

And here's the code :

DBHelper

```
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String TAG = DbHelper.class.getSimpleName();
    public static final String DB_NAME = "myapp.db";
    public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

    public static final String USER_TABLE = "users";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_USERNAME = "username";
    public static final String COLUMN_EMAIL = "email";
    public static final String COLUMN_PASS = "password";


    /*
    create table users(
        id integer primary key autoincrement,
        email text,
        password text);
     */
    public static final String CREATE_TABLE_USERS = "CREATE TABLE " + USER_TABLE + "("
            + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + COLUMN_USERNAME + " TEXT,"
            + COLUMN_EMAIL + " TEXT,"
            + COLUMN_PASS + " TEXT);";


    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_USERS);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + USER_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    /**
     * Storing user details in database
     * */
    public void addUser(String username,String email,String password) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_USERNAME, username);
        values.put(COLUMN_EMAIL, email);
        values.put(COLUMN_PASS, password);

        long id = db.insert(USER_TABLE, null, values);
        db.close();

        Log.d(TAG, "user inserted" + id);
    }

    public boolean getUser(String username, String email, String pass){
        //HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String selectQuery = "select * from  " + USER_TABLE + " where " +
                COLUMN_USERNAME + " = " + "'"+username+"'" + " and " + COLUMN_PASS + " = " + "'"+pass+"'";
        if(email != null)
            selectQuery += "and " + COLUMN_EMAIL + " = " + "'"+email+"'";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // Move to first row
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {

            return true;
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        return false;
    }
}
```

HomeActivity

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView nameuser, walletuser, mainmenus,
            pagetitle, pagesubtitle;

    Button btnguide;
    Animation atg, atgtwo, atgthree;
    ImageView imageView3;
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    Intent intent;
    private Session session;
    TextView btnLogout, btnDaftarBarang, btnTambah;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        session = new Session(this);

        if(!session.loggedin()){
            logout();
        }

        atg = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.atg);
        atgtwo = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.atgtwo);
        atgthree = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.atgthree);

        nameuser = findViewById(R.id.nameuser);
        walletuser = findViewById(R.id.walletuser);
        btnDaftarBarang = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.btnDaftarBarang);
        btnTambah = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.btnTambah);
        btnLogout = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.btnLogout);
        btnLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                logout();
            }
        });
        imageView3 = findViewById(R.id.imageView3);

        mainmenus = findViewById(R.id.mainmenus);

        pagetitle = findViewById(R.id.pagetitle);
        pagesubtitle = findViewById(R.id.pagesubtitle);

        btnguide = findViewById(R.id.btnguide);

        btnguide.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent a = new Intent(HomeActivity.this,PackageAct.class);
                startActivity(a);
            }
        });

        // pass an animation
        imageView3.startAnimation(atg);

        pagetitle.startAnimation(atgtwo);
        pagesubtitle.startAnimation(atgtwo);

        btnguide.startAnimation(atgthree);

        btnTambah.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent tambah = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, CrudActivity.class);
                startActivity(tambah);
            }
        });

        btnDaftarBarang.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //start recordlist activity
                startActivity(new Intent(HomeActivity.this, RecordListActivity.class));
            }
        });

    }

    private void logout(){
        session.setLoggedin(false);
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(HomeActivity.this,LoginActivity.class));
    }


}
```

Session.java

```
public class Session {
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    Context ctx;

    public Session(Context ctx){
        this.ctx = ctx;
        prefs = ctx.getSharedPreferences("myapp", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = prefs.edit();
    }

    public void setLoggedin(boolean logggedin){
        editor.putBoolean("loggedInmode",logggedin);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public boolean loggedin(){
        return prefs.getBoolean("loggedInmode", false);
    }
}
```

LoginActivity.java

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    private Button login;
    private EditText etUsername, etPass;
    private DbHelper db;
    private Session session;
    TextView RegisterDisini;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

            db = new DbHelper(this);
            session = new Session(this);
            login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
            etUsername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
            etPass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etPass);
            login.setOnClickListener(this);
            RegisterDisini = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.RegisterDisini);

            RegisterDisini.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent registerHere = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
                    startActivity(registerHere);
                }
            });

            if(session.loggedin()){
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this,HomeActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch(v.getId()){
                case R.id.btnLogin:
                    login();
                    break;
                default:
            }
        }

        private void login(){
            String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
            String pass = etPass.getText().toString();

            if(db.getUser(username,null,pass)){
                session.setLoggedin(true);
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class));
                finish();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong username/password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 1. Add the line, as per the comment, as below to the **LoginActivity**

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    public static final String INTENTEXTRAKEY_LOGGEDINUSERNAME = "iek_loggedinusername"; //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED THIS LINE

    private Button login;
```

## 2. In **LoginActivity** Change your login method as below :-

```
private void login(){
    String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
    String pass = etPass.getText().toString();

    if(db.getUser(username,null,pass)){
        session.setLoggedin(true);
        //startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class)); <<<<<<<<< OLD CODE
        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,HomeActivity.class); //<<<<<<<<<< NEW CODE
        intent.putExtra(INTENTEXTRAKEY_LOGGEDINUSERNAME,username); //<<<<<<<<<< NEW CODE
        startActivity(intent); //<<<<<<<<<< NEW CODE
        finish();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong username/password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

## 3. In the **HomeActivity** add the line as commented :-

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView nameuser, walletuser, mainmenus,
            pagetitle, pagesubtitle;

    Button btnguide;
    Animation atg, atgtwo, atgthree;
    ImageView imageView3;
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    Intent intent;
    private Session session;
    TextView btnLogout, btnDaftarBarang, btnTambah;

    String loggedinusername; //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED
```

## 4. Also in **HomeActivity** add the line as commented :-

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    session = new Session(this);
    loggedinusername = this.getIntent().getStringExtra(LoginActivity.INTENTEXTRAKEY_LOGGEDINUSERNAME); //<<<<<<<<<<ADDED
```

## 5. Again also in **HomeActivity** add the line as commented :-

```
    atg = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.atg);
    atgtwo = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.atgtwo);
    atgthree = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.atgthree);

    nameuser = findViewById(R.id.nameuser);
    nameuser.setText(loggedinusername); //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED
```

## Explanation

1. adds a constant for a value that will be used to define the key part of a key/value pair.
2. Adds an Intent Extra that has the constant as defined in 1 as the key and the username as the value.
3. Adds a class variable, **loggedinusername**, for the username (optional as you could get the Inten Extra directly, but this allows the username to be utilised elsewhere if need be.)
4. sets the **loggedinusername** variable according to the Intent Extra
5. sets the TextView to display the username as per the **loggedinusername** variable.

This is the recommended way of passing data from one activity to the next. You can pass many Intent Extras of varying types.

Comment: Sorry but why my textview show nothing? it doesn't display any username

Comment: 2019-06-02 14:30:15.837 1953-2100/system_process E/TaskPersister: File error accessing recents directory (directory doesn't exist?).

Comment: after `startActivity(intent)` try commenting out **finish()** i.e. have `//finish()`. You, also need to review your code after reading [Understand the Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle). As having `startActivity` and then `finish`, as you frequently do, will mess things up. You should either `finish` (return to the invoking activity) or `startActivity`, very unlikely both. Especially [Navigating between activities](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#tba)

Answer (score 0):

After login success pass username to your HomeActivity using intent

```
      private void login(){
        String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
        String pass = etPass.getText().toString();

        if(db.getUser(username,null,pass)){
            session.setLoggedin(true);
            Intent intent=new Intent(this,HomeActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("username",username);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong username/password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }


// now get Username in HomeActivity like this

 String username=getIntent().getStringExtra("username");
  if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(username)){
    // and set on your textview here
     nameuser.setText(""+username);
 }
```

Comment: Too many error : cannot resolve symbol sqLiteDatabase, cursor and you don't show me how to get value from intent and set it.So i can display username from sqlite database after login in textView

Comment: Still error, the code's similar like this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56272602/display-username-from-sqlite-database-after-login-in-textview?noredirect=1#comment99162091_56272602

Comment: getUser() method will return String type and pass only two params(email and pass) to getUser() method

Comment: do you want login using username and pass?

Comment: Nope, i want to show username in my textview layout example when im login using username 'Kira', my textview in my layout will change into 'Kira'. I already success login with username and pass with my code.

Comment: Sorry, maybe you don't understand what i mean.There's no problem about login in my code that i post here. I just want to display my username when i already register & login in my textview on layout activity_home with code <TextView
    android:id="@+id/nameuser"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"/>

Comment: I want to create something like Hello Welcome Kira (TextView) when i already success login

Comment: after sucess pass usernam in intent to homeActivity and get in homeActivity